# Hivecontext and hive results are not consistent for decimal values spark

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, databricks

I have a hive table where the decimal values are saved as bytes. When I query the table from hive the values are properly fetched. However when I retrieve the values using hive context, the values are not proper. I had the following observations,

1) When fetched from hive context decimal values are appearing like value * 10 power 18

2) Some values are appearing as null. However these values are proper when queried in hive.

This issue is observed only for decimals saved as bytes in hive.

This issue is seen for values > 100 . For values < 100 value is getting displayed properly

Comment: Can you post an example of the values where you're seeing this discrepancy. What are these `some values` that are appearing as `NULL`?

Comment: @philantrovert : The value appears like \u0000<some junk characters>\u0000\u0000

Comment: And you mean to say that `<some junk charactees>` are not originally in the source data? BTW, you can remove Unicode nulls `\u0000` by using `regexp_replace` in the query. Something like `select regexp_replace(column_name, '\0', '') as column_name from table_name`

Comment: @philantrovert The values are appearing in source avro. I can see byte values like \u0000Â§#Â·ÃÂÂ¼Ã\u0000\u0000 which are parsed properly when called from hive. However when queried using hive context they return null value